# Switching between portrait and landscape resets to screen 0

Tags: android, indexing, scrollbar

I'm using the T-Mobile G1.  What I have is a **3 tab app**(that is based on the example of the **TAB APP**).  Whenever you switch between portrait and landscape by opening/closing the keyboard,

(1)the screen(s) do not scroll and,

(2)if you are on screen 1 or 2 and open/close the keyboard, the app will reset to screen 0.

I have no idea how to fix the error or where to look for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when the screen rotates your activity is destroyed and recreated in the new orientation.  See [Configuration Changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) for details.

This means that your activity needs to properly save its state in [onSaveInstanceBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and restore it in [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the situation that Mayra describes, define the property

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

in your activity inside in your Manifest.xml

```
     <activity android:name="myActivity"            
...
...
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"        
        />
```